# What is considered carrying שלא לצורך on Yom-Tov?

Tags: yom-tov

Carrying outside (where there is no eiruv) on Yom Tov is only permitted if the carrying is לצורך יום-טוב - (for a purpose needed on Yom Tov), but carrying when one does not need it on Yom-Tov is forbidden, [שולחן ערוך אורח חיים סימן תקיח:א]

Is carrying a garment/hat etc., which can just as well be worn on his person, (which would then not be considered "carrying"), considered carrying שלא לצורך יום-טוב, since he does not need the "carrying" itself, or as long as the transfer from one place to the other is for צורך יום טוב it is permitted even though he  could do it without carrying?

Another example of this may be, If one carried something on YT from point A to point B via an area which had no eiruv, and he could just as well get it to point B without going outside of the eiruv, would this be considered הוצאה שלא לצורך יום טוב since he does not need the "carrying" outside of the eiruv?

Are these 2 the same or different?

Comment: Isn't he choosing the method based on confort or ease? That's already a tzorekh. He would only choose to carry the hat if he didn't want to currently wear it (eg. it flaps in the wind or is not fashionable or something)

Comment: @DoubleAA your'e right if there was a difference, even of confort or ease, then it would be צורך יו"ט but what if there isn't? My question is if a צורך is required for the "carrying" or as long as the transfer is לצורך its enough.

Comment: Cooking is permitted only _l'tzorech y"t_. Many people eat carrots raw. Is one allowed to cook carrots on _y"t_ for _y"t_? Maybe, since he doesn't need the cooking itself but only for the carrot to get to his stomach, it's forbidden. Seems like a direct analogue to your case. I've never heard of anyone forbidding cooking carrots, or forbidding carrying clothing.

Comment: @msh210 If  for any reason he prefers eating the carrots cooked, that would be his tzorech YT. So too, , As pointed out by DoubleAA, if the person carrying the coat was carrying rather than wearing it for reason of comfort, ease, or any other reason, then the carrying would indeed be tzorech YT.  My question was "Is carrying a garment/hat etc., which can **just as well** be worn on his person... or "If one carried something..., and he could **just as well** get it to point B without going outside of the eiruv... would that carrying be considered shelo l'tzorech YT"?